# Does memory configuration really matter with fair scheduler?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, cloudera, hadoop2

We have a hadoop cluster with fair scheduler configured. We used to see the scenario whan there were not many jobs in the cluster to run, the running job was trying to take as much as memory and cores available.

With the Fair scheduler does executor memory and cores are really matter for the spark Jobs? Or does it depend upon the fair scheduler to decide how much to give?

Comment: @Abhinav, I have few doubts based on your answer. Consider my cluster is fair scheduled and jobs are written to run properly in distributing environment 1) if my cluster is free while the job is running at that point in time it’s up to scheduler to give min and max resources (even the job submitted/ requested with less resources by user) ? . 2) in the production environment do you really see the need of tuning min and max resources for each of spark job ?.

Comment: @WiilamR 1) When you submit a job, scheduler's work is to assign the job in the queue. On the other Hand Application Manager is responsible for providing the resources and building containers for that job to be executed so talking about min/max, it depends upon the size of your job. But it is confirmed that if the job had to use 100% resources, no one is going to stop it. 2.) In production env. we don't really need to tune the resource allocation but we choose not to use Fair Share, we use capacity Scheduler which is better as per my knowledge. So the second question I can't answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the policy of Fair Scheduler that the first job assigned to it will have all the resources provided.

When we run the second job, all the resources will be divided in to (available resources)/(no. of jobs)

Now the main thing to focus is, how much maximum number of container memory you have given to run the job. If it is equal to the total number of resources available then it's genuine for your job to use all the resources.